# Julia updates variable in a loop

Tags: julia

I have a code that programs a value function iteration. The code is translate from Matlab. The first iteration rolls nicely, but in the second, the old value function gets updated at some point wrongly, though the second iteration still produces the equivalent result from matlab.

First, I declare the variables here:

```
sigma = 1.5;
delta = 0.1;
beta  = 0.95;
alpha = 0.30;
ks    = 1.0;
csy   = 0.2;
kmin  = 0.1*ks;
kmax  = 1.1*ks;
nbk   = 20;
devk  = (kmax-kmin)/(nbk-1);
k     = linspace(kmin,kmax,nbk)';
v0    = zeros(nbk,1);
v0    = (csy*k.^alpha).^(1-sigma);
v0    = v0';
v     = zeros(nbk,1);
ik1   = zeros(nbk,1);
iter  = 1;
crit  = 1;
tol   = 1e-6;
```

second, I execute this (it is a while loop), but I prefer executing it one iteration after the other):

```
 for i=1:nbk
      imin =  max(ceil(((1-delta)*k[i]-kmin)/devk)+1.0,1);
      imax =  min(floor((k[i]^alpha+(1-delta)*k[i]-kmin)/devk)+1.0,nbk);

      imin=trunc(Int, imin);
      imax=trunc(Int, imax);
      c = k[i]^alpha+(1-delta)*k[i]-k[imin:imax];
      u = (c.^(1-sigma)-1)/(1-sigma);
      (v[i],itmp)= findmax(u+beta*v0[imin:imax]);
      ik1[i] = imin-1+itmp;
   end;

  v0  = v;
```

Running this second part the first time prints correctly v and the error:

```
[-9.41322; -6.19362; -4.35414; -3.01282; -1.95198; -1.07545; -0.330322; 0.316098; 0.885574; 1.39337; 1.85067; 2.29198; 2.69438; 3.06364; 3.40432; 3.72013; 4.0141; 4.28875; 4.54618; 4.79853]
error:5.124021319754114
```

Running it a second time, leads to an error because now v0 becomes I don't know why equal to v (though v is still produced correctly, like in Matlab):

```
[-7.06807; -4.7177; -3.24724; -2.16729; -1.30218; -0.578569; 0.0429673; 0.586699; 1.09022; 1.54641; 1.98317; 2.37955; 2.7416; 3.07412; 3.38098; 3.66532; 3.92974; 4.18466; 4.42981; 4.66936]
error:0.0
```

So the error is zero, which should not be the case after two iterations. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you set `v0 = v`, both variables refer to the same area in memory, i.e, when you try to modify one, you actually modify both at the same time.

Use `copy!(v0, v)` to copy the content of `v` into `v0`. Then the arrays can be modified independently.